# Input name with (whitespace)

Tags: c, removing-whitespace

Can anybody can help me with my code

```
void gotoxy(int, int);
void clrscr();
void dispMenu();

int main(void){
    int choice;

    choice = 0;
menu:
    dispMenu();
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    if(choice==1){
        clrscr();

        char name[100];

        printf("Please Input your Complete name: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", &name);

        printf("Your name is: %s \n", name);
    }

    getch();
    goto menu;
}

void dispMenu(){
    gotoxy(23,9);
    printf("List of C-Lang Activities\n");
    gotoxy(23,11);
    printf("1. Input Name");
    gotoxy(23,12);
    printf("2. (blank) \n");
    gotoxy(23,13);
    printf("3. (blank) \n");
    gotoxy(23,14);
    printf("4. (blank)\n");
    gotoxy(23,15);
    printf("5. (blank)\n");
    gotoxy(23,17);
    printf("Please Enter the Number of your choice: ");
}

void gotoxy(int x, int y){
    HANDLE hConsoleOutput;
    COORD dxCursorPosition;
    dxCursorPosition.X = x;
    dxCursorPosition.Y = y;

    hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsoleOutput, dxCursorPosition);
}

void clrscr(){
    system("cls");
}
```

I have a problem when I'm trying to put my program to a table menu this what will appear:

[image]

output will be like this

```
Please Input your Complete Name: John Kenneth

Your Name is: John Kenneth
```

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s", &name);`  don't use `&` here and `%[` is itself a specifier , so don't put `s` after it .

Comment: Please refer here -http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is with

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", &name);
```

It has 2 issues:

1. `%[` expects a `char*`, but you provide a `char(*)[100]`.
2. `s` is not part of the `%[` specifier.

Fixing those issues, you get

```
scanf("%[^\n]", name);
```

but you'll notice that you get the same output again. That's because `%[^\n]` will fail if the first character to be read is a `\n`. Wondering where this character came from? Remember pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing a number for the previous `scanf`? This character prevails in the `stdin` making `scanf("%[^\n]", name);` fail.

You can fix this as well by instructing `scanf` to discard/skip all whitespace characters before reading by adding a whitespace character before the format string, say, a space, like this:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", name);
```

Now it'll work as expected.

Note that it is better to limit the number of characters to be read by `scanf` by using a length specifier so that you are free some buffer overflows. This can be done by using:

```
scanf(" %99[^\n]", name);
```

I've used 99 as the extra space must be reserved for the NUL-terminator(`'\0'`) at the end of the string.

Also, it is better to check the return value of `scanf` to see if it was successful:

```
if(scanf(" %99[^\n]", name) != 1)
    /* Input error or EOF */
```

Answer (score 2):

Use standard function `fgets`. For example

```
fgets( name, sizeof( name ), stdin );
name[strcspn( name, "\n" )] = '\0';
```

Take into account that it is a bad idea to use the goto statement. You should forget that there is the goto statement in C. Use instead a `while` or `do-while` loop.